# Django with AWS S3, Debug False not working in production

Tags: python, django, nginx, amazon-s3

I am using Django 4.2.5. I have deployed projects using Nginx, Docker, and AWS S3 before.But now, when Debug is True, there are no issues with AWS S3, but when Debug is set to False, CSS is not working.

> GET https://bucketname.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/static/CACHE/css/output.bdb8c01056f5.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

> https://events.launchdarkly.com/events/bulk/88120c8d0102a7  net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

> "This XML File Does Not Have Style Information"

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>static/CACHE/css/output.bdb8c01056f5.css</Key>
<RequestId></RequestId>
<HostId></HostId>
</Error>
```

I have configured the AWS S3 bucket policy, CORS, and made the necessary adjustments.
I even created a new bucket and ran collectstatic with Debug set to False, but the issue persists. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.Thank you!

```
AWS_S3_GZIP = True
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY =os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_S3_REGION_NAME')
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE=False
AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_VERIFY = True
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"staticfiles")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static"),
)


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',   
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = [
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
]
```